# Unable to connect to TCP Server from external machine

Tags: sockets, tcp, rust

I have written a basic TCP server in Rust but I am unable to access it from a different computer on the same network. It is not a network problem since I also wrote a similar Python TCP server and the test client is able to connect to that server successfully.

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;
use std::str;

fn handle_read(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buf;
    // clear out the buffer so we don't send garbage
    buf = [0; 512];

    // Read and discard any data from the client since this is a read only server.
    let _ = match stream.read(&mut buf) {
        Err(e) => panic!("Got an error: {}", e),
        Ok(m) => m,
    };

    println!("Got some data");

    // Write back the response to the TCP stream
    match stream.write("This works!".as_bytes()) {
        Err(e) => panic!("Read-Server: Error writing to stream {}", e),
        Ok(_) => (),
    }

}

pub fn read_server() {
    // Create TCP server
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6009").unwrap();
    println!("Read server listening on port 6009 started, ready to accept");

    // Wait for incoming connections and respond accordingly
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Got an error");
            }
            Ok(stream) => {

                println!("Received a connection");
                // Spawn a new thread to respond to the connection request
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_read(stream);

                });

            }    
        }

    }
}

fn main() {
    read_server();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6009").unwrap();
```

If you bind to `127.0.0.1:xxxx`, the socket can only listen from the localhost interface. To allow external connections, bind to `0.0.0.0` instead, so that it can accept connections from all network interfaces.

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:6009").unwrap();
```

See [Why would I bind on a different server than 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988808/why-would-i-bind-on-a-different-server-than-127-0-0-1) for detail.

---

BTW, (1)

```
// not idiomatic
let _ = match stream.read(&mut buf) {
    Err(e) => panic!("Got an error: {}", e),
    Ok(m) => m,
};
```

You could use [`Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) for this.

```
// better
stream.read(&mut buf).expect("Got an error");
```

(2)

```
// not idiomatic
match stream.write("This works!".as_bytes()) {
    Err(e) => panic!("Read-Server: Error writing to stream {}", e),
    Ok(_) => (),
}
```

instead of `"aaa".as_bytes()` you could simply write `b"aaa"`.

```
// better
stream.write(b"This works!").expect("Read-Server: Error writing to stream");
```

Comment: Thanks @kennytm, I figured out that issue before you answered and didn't get the time to update my question. It was exactly as you mentioned, setting my IP as 0.0.0.0 now has my server working. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: `Result::expect` will screw the line reported. Thus `if let Err (err) = ... {panic! ("message, {}", err)}` is often more helpful when the error actually happens.

Comment: @ArtemGr Hopefully someone will push forward https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rfrfc-better-option-result-error-messages so `expect`'s line number is correct. But with a unique-enough message it should not be hard to find our which `expect` is going wrong.